# PHP Open excel file with password

Tags: php, excel

Is there a way to open an excel file password protected in PHP?

I have looked at the usual library (PHPExcel) but from looking at the discussions it does not support it.  Can anyone give me a way on how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean, is there a way to use PHP to open a password protected Excel file? And at what level is the password applied?

Comment: Yes.  The password is applied on the whole document (opening the file will prompt an input for the password).  I am able to open the file and extract its contents (to be inserted into a DB) using PHPExcel but I could not open an excel file which is password protected.  Are there any libraries I could use that could do this?  Thank you.